# Views Link to Teaser

Tags: nodes, javascript

I'm using JCarousel with Views. I've been able to get my content working fine and linked properly to their nodes in a modal window using colorbox-load. I'd like to be able to open up only the teaser content in the window. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

If the link in your View is something like that `node/XXXX` I think it not possible, or at least you should modify the node.tpl.php and add a condition inside to show only teaser or full content according the context (from jCarousel or not).

Another solution it's to create another view, that will display only the Tease and point your links (from the view jCarousel) to that view. This view need to show node (tease) and accept an argument (nid).

Comment: Thanks for the recommendations! I went ahead and created a new view (teaser) and linked that via colorobx. The only problem is that it's loading the whole page vs just the content.

Comment: I ended up using Colorbox node, worked great!